# css width & height don't bind with @Hostbinding

Tags: angular

I'm trying to dynamically bind css class with @HostBinding in a directive. Every thing seems to be working but in a closer look width and height  property of a class are ommited.  Eventualy  component with binded class  is kind of weird displayed. Not only two elements are displayed instead of one, but their size is wrong. I would be pleased  for any sugestion. Below a link to project.
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ppgxta)

By the way I've tried also with Renderer2, but the efect is the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Eventualy component with binded class is kind of weird displayed. Not only two elements are displayed instead of one, but their size is wrong.

This is because of incorrect CSS being used.

- `height` and `width` property values do not have unit specified.

```css
/* Incorrect - units are missing */
height: 300;
width: 50;

/* Correct usage - specified 'px' as unit (could vary as per use case) */
height: 300px;
width: 50px;
```

- Instead of `border-style` maybe you want to use `border`

```css
/* Incorrect usage */
border-style: 1px solid black;

/* Correct usage - if only border-style required */
border-style: solid;

/* Correct usage - if other border properties required too */
border: 1px solid black;
```

- The above changes will ensure correct CSS usage, but still won't give expected result.
  The Angular component host element (in your case `app-child`) will have `display: inline` style until explicitly specified one. So you may need to specify `display: block;` for the desired end result.

Comment: I have tried with different units. Finaly for the purpose of this topic in a hurry, I have forgotten to specify the correct units. Nevertheless thank you so much for an answer. Of couse display: inline was the cause.

Comment: why app-child has display:inline by default? And also why display:inline makes  app-child component so splitted? How to achieve a few app-child components displayed inline - side by side? Thanks